# How to make jQuery callback like .done in AJAX?

Tags: jquery

How to make jQuery callback like .done in AJAX?

I need to do like it:

```
myMethod(args)
    .done(function(args) {
        console.log(true);
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit unclear what you're asking. Is this what you want?

```
function myMethod(){

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    // simulate something async:
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.resolve({foo: true}); // pass some dummy data
    }, 500);

    return dfd.promise();
}

myMethod().done(function(args){
    console.log(args.foo);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9MRr9/1/

Read more about deferred objects here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: thank you. But can I define my callback? Like it:

`myMethod().myCallback(function(...) {
    ...
});`

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you want to do exactly. You can use `$.ajax` to make the ajax call and provide a function after the request is done.
Create your own function and pass in a callback.

#### Sample

```
function doRequest(callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "yourUrl",
    }).done(callback));
}

doRequest(function(data) {
  // do something
});
```

#### More Information:

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)